# sonar unable to create JDBC datasource

Tags: ruby, json, sonarqube, sonar-runner

When I try to run sonar-runner from the command line for a project, I get a 500 error:

```
INFO  - Install plugins
INFO  - Install JDBC driver
INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 12.320s
Final Memory: 7M/152M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to download [http://localhost:9000/api/server]. Response code: 500
```

**UpDate**

I think this is caused by conflit with local ruby version as I have in sonar.log this description:

```
ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://localhost:9000/api/server/index?format=json
undefined method `generate' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x10b4e1f2>
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:470:in `JSON'
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found an old bug in the SonarQube issue tracker (http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-3579) that describes the same problem, it is indeed a compatibility issue. It is suggested as a workaround to unset GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME variables before launching Sonar.

I put the following two lines into the sonar startup script:

```
unset GEM_PATH
unset GEM_HOME
```

A restart of the sonar service solved the problem for me in SonarQube Version 5.1.1 and SonarQube Runner 2.4.